# Index Coverage - Redirect Error from Index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I thought I solved this problem two years ago but now since a couple of weeks I get harassed by the Google Search Console with "Index Coverage" referring to the /index.php of my homepage (all variants of my website are listed in the Search Console and I have a canonical URL in the head part). Also, if I call my `www.xxx./index.php` it says "Page doesn't work - too many redirects".

Now I know this is not directly a programming issue, but since it involses the htaccess, which is somehow red and black art and just voodoo, I can't get my code to be working correctly/my site being accessible and correctly redirected.

My .htaccess adresses the problem the following. I already tried switching out and deleting parts but it keeps sticking around like a reckless goblin:

```
// This should redirect to http with www

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

// This should redirect index.php requests - to be redirected to https://www.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
// Redirect from capital Index.php to index.php 
RewriteRule ^Index\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]

// This redirects from /html and /index requests combined with .php to the https:// version
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

// I'm not sure anymore...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

**Edit:** I feel that the problem is - like my browser and the search console says - that too many redirects happen (to `www.xxx.de/index.php`). So I tried out different .htaccess parts and deleting some to minimize the redirections, which for now doesn't seem to work.
I assembled the parts together on my own (not via a framework), I guess that explains sth.

**Edit 2:** After I deleted line after line and tested the effects, the only part that affects the `/index.php` is as expected the RewriteRule `^index\.(html?|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`, but then the website is also simply accessible under `/index.php`

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained each section of your .htaccess with the desired result, and what it does not do that you want it to do.

Comment: Did you use a framework to generate this .htaccess? E.g. Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal? Compare the file with the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Index\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Index\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

and now /index.php is correctly redirected to my www.xxx.net/ without any loop.

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Since essentially what you want is to redirect the users that referenced `/index.php` to `/`?

Comment: thanks for your help! I deleted the block, but the message and the error stays. After I deleted line after line and tested the effects, the only part that affects the `/index.php` is as expected the `RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`, but then the website is also simply accessible under `/index.php`

Comment: Ok. In that case why are you rewriting the URL with itself (i.e. %{REQUEST_URI})? That's most likely what causes the loop...

Comment: The error is still coming, but I replaced it in a similar way, see below. Hope it works in every way now. Thanks again for your effort!